# Algebra to pick random element from a set

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, sampling, random-functions

Lets define set $G$:
$$G = \{ 1,2, \dots,n \space | \space n \in \mathbb{N} \} \text{ and }\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$$

What is the algebraic notation to build set $Y$ by picking randomly 20 elements from $G$, without replacement ?
$$Y = \{?\}$$

Comment: If you just write $Y\subseteq G, |Y|=20$ ($Y$ is a subset of $G$ and $Y$ has 20 elements), does it give you what you want? (What I wrote here is a description of an arbitrary 20-element subset of $G$, however it doesn't say how, randomly or otherwise, this subset has been obtained.)

Comment: Do *|Y|=20* means that 20 elements are taken in *G*?
If I make no mistake element can't be double in set, so it is like a sampling without replacement ?

Comment: This is one (frequently used) notation for the number of elements (cardinality) of set. $|X|=n$ means "set $X$ has $n$ elements". See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality. So yes, it is like sampling without replacement.

Comment: Yes ok, it do part of the job! But it don't express random picking?

Comment: It doesn't, and to be honest I am not sure myself how to easily express that notion, so I would let other people chip in. The problem is that any algebraic notation about "random picking" would need to specify the precise rules (what is the probability for which set - e.g. among the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$ maybe the probabilities to pick one of $1,2,\ldots,20$ is $\frac{1}{20}$ while the probability to pick any of $21,22,\ldots,100$ is $0$ - which then mandates "random" $Y$ to be $\{1,2,\ldots,20\}$... This invokes notions such as "probability space" etc. - probably not what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as $$Y \subseteq G \space \text{ with }\space \#Y=20 \space \text{($\#$ stands for cardinality).}$$

If you want to use this for a proof, it satisfies to write for example

$$Y \subseteq G \space \text{ with }\space \#Y=20$$ and $\forall n \in Y$ chosen **arbitrarily**. This notes that the values are chosen randomly. I hoped this helped you out.

Comment: $\forall n \in Y$ means for all *n* in ***Y*** ?

Comment: Yes, $\forall$ means $\text{'for all'}$.

Answer (score 1):

Would this suffice?

$$Y = \{ y \text{ }| \text{ } y = f(x), f:[n] \mapsto N, |f| = n\}$$

This reads:
$Y$ is the set of elements from some bijective function $f$ which maps the first $n$ naturals to some natural number.
The fact $f$ is bijective implies there are no duplicates.

Comment: Yes, it do the job to precise that there is no random duplicate. It is interesting because as *Y* is a set, I guess that it cannot contain duplicates (right ?) but duplicates are possible during the sampling process (e.g. 16 may be sampled 2 times resulting *|Y|* = 19 when sampled elements in *|G|* =20...?

Comment: @RPO By definition a set contains no duplicates. I suspect you might be implementing this on a program? If that is the case look into HashSets, or whatever the equivalent for the language you use is. These are data structures which upon insertion check for duplicates for you, so a HashSet of size 20 will always have 20 distinct elements.
Usually, HashSets are synonymous to classic sets, and Lists are synonymous to multisets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: Yes, I run it under R ; could you check if my following proposal cover the needs? ;)

Answer (score 0):

So to summary, we define set *G*:

$$G = \left \{ 1,2,...,n \: |\: n\in \mathbb{N}  \right \}\:\text{where }n\geq 20$$

Set *Y* is built with randomly sampled unique elements from *G* so that:

$$Y_{|G|} = \left \{ y \: |\:y=f(x), f:\left [ |G| \right ] \mapsto \mathbb{N},|f|=|G| \right \}$$

With probability *P(e)* for elements *e* from *G* to be in *Y*:

$$P(e)=\frac{(N-n)!}{N!}\: with \: e \in G, \: N=|G|, \: n=|Y|$$

Right ?

Comment: The probability of an element occurring depends on the sampling algorithm itself.

Comment: Does defining the probability implicitly means the sampling algorithm (or its 'family')?

Comment: Suppose you have a "fair" algorithm which gives each element $e \in G$ an equal chance of being chosen. Then the probability for $P(x \in G) = \frac{1}{|G|}$. If we instead wish to find the probability of a particular selection $s = \{ a,b,c,d,...\}$ occuring, then we have $\frac{1}{P(s \in G^*)}$ $=$ $|G|\choose n$ where $n$ is the number of elements to be sampled.

It is worthwhile to mention that there's no such thing as a random number generating program. So whatever algorithm you use will have some bias.

Comment: In this sentence : $$Y_{|G|} = \left \{ y \: |\:y=f(x), f:\left [ |G| \right ] \mapsto \mathbb{N},|f|=|G| \right \}$$ what is the length of Y? Do I need to write $$Y_{|G|} = \left \{ y \: |\:y=f(x), f:\left [ |G| \right ] \mapsto \mathbb{N},|f|=20 \right \}$$ if I want |Y| = 20 ?

Comment: Actually there's a mistake in my notation, because what I wrote down in my edit implies that $Y = G$ since $|f| = |G|$.
The correct way to write this would be:
$Y_{n} = \{y \text{ }| y = f(x), f:[n] \mapsto \mathbb{N}, |f| = n, n \leq |G|\}$

Here n is going to be |Y_n|. It follows since $f$ is a bijection and $Y_n$ is the set of outputs of $f$.